# cloning a linux image using dd

Tags: linux, devices, dd, cloning

If I wish to clone my Linux image using the dd utility, I can do for example `dd if=/dev/SDX of=/dev/SDY`, where SDX is the internal memory device where the Linux image is stored, and SDY is the external memory device I would like to copy it to.

However if I do this without cloning to a different memory device and use the same internal memory, example: `dd if=/dev/SDX of=/home/my_dir/my_image.img` , this is creating an image file in the same internal memory device that the actual image resides. This seems to work fine for me, but how does it?  `/home/my_dir/` is inside */dev/SDX* which I am cloning?

Comment: why not just copy the relevant files instead of the entire image?

Comment: @StrongBad I need a complete clone of my image to distribute to others

Comment: <pre>
this shouldnt work. you cannot put an 8G image inside the same filesystem with 6G of free space. possible explanation: if=/dev/SDX has read errors (bad sector, or alike) and output image is smaller than the disk. try again the dd with:

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Someone suggested edits for my post and appended /my_image.img to /dev/SDX . I reverted now

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Sorry I edited my question now as it was completely messed up by the suggested edits

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, this *seems* to work fine – with the emphasis on "seems".

To simplify the explanation, I assume a legacy filesystem without journaling (like ext2).
As soon as dd starts, the file `my_image.img` is created. The information that this file exists and *where* it *physically* resides on the disk, is stored in the filesystem's index (think of it like a "table of contents"). The file's final size is not yet known, so it takes up a minimal default size (this is usually not shown to the user application).
As data is written to the file, it grows and the index is updated on regular intervals. However, the index resides on the disk, too. Once dd copied the index, the index in the copy is no longer updated. If you actually tried using the copy, you would notice that it is incomplete.

All this is academical of course, as dd cannot fit the full image file inside itself (unless you employ some kind of compression).

With commands like these, you can try it for yourself:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=demo.raw bs=1M count=256 # create a dummy "partition" for demonstration
mkfs.ext4 demo.raw # create ext4 filesystem
target=$(mktemp -d) # create a temporary mountpoint
sudo mount demo.raw $target # mount the filesystem
sudo chown $USER $target # make filesystem root writable for current user
dd if=demo.raw of=$target/inner.raw bs=1M # copy fileystem into itself – error as expected (no space left on device)
rm $target/inner.raw
dd if=demo.raw bs=1M | gzip -c > $target/inner.raw.gz # copy fileystem into itself, using compression
gzip -c $target/inner.raw.gz > inner.raw # decompress image
sudo mount inner.raw /mnt # mount inner copy – error as expected (copy is an incomplete file)
sudo umount $target
rm demo.raw inner.raw
```

Comment: Even by piping and compressing it using gzip as I done before also, how does this even work , because we are copying the 8GB image, compressing it and storing it in the same file system which we are cloning. I understand how it works when copying to a different medium, but not inside its own medium, if you understand what I mean

Comment: You ponder how this could work. But your feeling is correct – it does not actually work. I updated my answer.

Comment: I have tried it this way dd if=/dev/sdX | gzip -c > /home/my_dir/my_image.img.gz and it works (appears to work fine), so i'm confused even more

Answer (score 0):

this shouldnt work.
you cannot put an 8G RAW image inside the same filesystem with 6G of free space. 
possible explanation: /dev/SDX has read errors (bad sector, or alike), and dd stopped before reaching the end of the disk, resulting in the output image smaller than the disk (so it fits). try again the dd with:

```
# dd if=/dev/SDX oflag=direct conv=noerror,notrunc of=/path/image.img
```

and also check the size of disk:

```
# df -h
```

and the size of the generated image:

```
# ls -lh /path/image.img
```

Comment: Even if I copy and compress it like this : dd if=/dev/sdX | gzip -c > path/my_image.img.gz  , how does it still work because my confusion is not about the file size but the fact that we are copying a linux image into the same file system which we are cloning?

Comment: Let's say for example this : dd if=/dev/sdX | gzip -c > /home/my_dir/my_image.img.gz   . Isn't /home/my_dir inside the file system in /dev/sdX ?? I'm confused with this

Comment: Yes, the image file is inside the filesystem you created an image of. And the copy won't be usable (for the reasons I mentioned in my answer).